# Displaying Column Description on Hover without SharePoint Desinger

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column-formatting

Is there a way to show the description of a column of a SharePoint online list when the mouse is hovered on in the modern experience without SharePoint Desinger?

Maybe similar to this one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230765/displaying-column-description-on-hover) but in the modern experience.

Answer (score 1):

For modern experience,you could add a SPFX Extension to add the js file to page. And you could add the code in the link you shared to to js file directly.
https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss(demo on add CSS file,you could change it to add JS file),

And you could use this to determine whether it is the desired page.

```
if ((window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('listname') > 0))
```